# MySQL cartesian product between two SELECT statements

Tags: mysql, select, join

I want to perform a cartesian product between two SELECT statements as

```
SELECT 1, 2     INNER JOIN     SELECT 3, 4 ;
```

I expect the result to be every combination of (1,2) with (3,4), like:

```
1  3
2  3
1  4
2  4
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the CROSS JOIN clause

```
SELECT MyTable1.Col1, MyTable2.Col2
FROM MyTable1
CROSS JOIN MyTable2
```

where MyTable1 has two rows containing 1 and 2; and MyTable2 has two rows containing 3 and 4.

Comment: `cross join` == `inner join` [MySQL 5.0](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Comment: Even more, cross join == inner join == join

Comment: In MySQL, JOIN, CROSS JOIN, and INNER JOIN are syntactic equivalents they are not same.
INNER JOIN and , (comma) are semantically equivalent in the absence of a join condition: both produce a Cartesian product between the specified tables (that is, each and every row in the first table is joined to each and every row in the second table).
So join==inner join but not true for cross join == inner join

Comment: There's a pretty big reason to use `CROSS JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` or `JOIN`, though, and it's not for what they produce - it greatly assists with readability.  I can't count how many times someone mistakenly has a cartesian product in their query and didn't notice, so joins missing conditions are often one of the first things I review.  A `CROSS JOIN` makes it crystal clear that the cartesian product is intentional and has been considered.  Same deal when selecting as multiple `FROM` tables, readability and intention suffer.

Answer (score 17):

If you specify your tables with out any `JOIN ON` clause or equalities/conditionins in the `WHERE` clause you'll get the catesian product you're looking for.

```
SELECT table1.field1, table2.field2
FROM table1, table2
```

will give you what you're asking for. Showing it more explicitly...

```
SELECT * FROM table1;
+--------+
| field1 |
+--------+
|      1 |
|      2 |
+--------+

SELECT * FROM table2;
+--------+
| field2 |
+--------+
|      3 |
|      4 |
+--------+

SELECT table1.field1, table2.field2 FROM table1, table2;
+--------+--------+
| field1 | field2 |
+--------+--------+
|      1 |      3 |
|      2 |      3 |
|      1 |      4 |
|      2 |      4 |
+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select v1, v2
from
  (select 1 as v1 union
   select 2) t1,
  (select 3 as v2 union
   select 4) t2
```

or even simpler:

```
select *
from
  (select 1 union
   select 2) t1,
  (select 3 union
   select 4) t2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql> select * from
    ->   (select 1 x union select 2 union select 3 union select 4) t
    ->   join
    ->   (select 1 y union select 2 union select 3) tt;
+---+---+
| x | y |
+---+---+
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 |
+---+---+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Removing the word `join` gives exactly the same result.

```
select * from
  (select 1 x union select 2 union select 3 union select 4) t,
  (select 1 y union select 2 union select 3) tt;
```

Answer (score 0):

With the using this your format is not as you are saying 
`A(1,2) and B(3,4)`
then the **cross join** will perform it like this:

```
SELECT Table1.Col1, Table2.Col2
FROM Table1
CROSS JOIN Table2
```

`(A*B)= (1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4)`