# Split a row into multiple rows based on a column value SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following "Order Table" :

```
    Item        Quantity
    pencil      2
    pen         1
    Notebook    4
```

I need the result like :

```
  Item        Quantity
  pencil      1
  pencil      1
  pen         1
  Notebook    1
  Notebook    1
  Notebook    1
  Notebook    1
```

Comment: You want a cross join: see this question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481396/mysql-cartesian-product-between-two-select-statements

Comment: What database platform?  SQL Server; MySQL?

Comment: sql server.. basically i want the item to be repeated the number of times as the initial quantity ordered, and quantity to be displayed as 1 in the final output for each item

Comment: @Surbhit why have a quantity at all in the output if it's always going to be 1? Just display the quantity as read from the DB. It will make your output easier to read and your code easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify which RDBMS you are using, so how you generate the numbers will depend on that (maybe a recursive CTE for SQL Server, using DUAL for Oracle, etc.). I've only written code to handle the data that you've shown, but you'll obviously need to account for numbers larger than four in the final solution.

```
SELECT
    MT.sr_no,
    MT.item_name,
    1 AS quantity
FROM
    My_Table MT
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT 1 AS nbr UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS nbr UNION ALL
        SELECT 3 AS nbr UNION ALL SELECT 4 AS nbr
    ) N ON N.nbr <= MT.quantity
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the recursive query using common table expression to generate number duplicate rows according to the quantity field as below

```
WITH cte (sno,item,quantity,rnum)
AS
(
    SELECT sno,item,quantity, 1 as rnum
    FROM [Order]

    UNION ALL

    SELECT cte.sno,cte.item,cte.quantity, rnum+1
    FROM [Order] JOIN cte ON [Order].sno = cte.sno
    AND cte.rnum < [Order].quantity
)
SELECT item,1 AS Quantity 
FROM cte 
ORDER BY sno
```